# C++ Function pointer wrapper throwing error when invoking

Tags: c++, templates

I've been having some trouble recently with an invoker class I've created. Reason is so I can parse an address through the class constructor and have it handle calling methods that are in memory. Problem is, when I go to return a class object type, it throws an error "Cannot convert from std::string to InvokerType". Any help is appreciated.

```
template <class InvokerType>
class Invoker {
public:
    Invoker(std::intptr_t address) :
        address(address)
    {  }

    template<class... Arguments>
    InvokerType invoke(Arguments&&... parameters) {
        InvokerType func = (InvokerType)this->address;
        return (InvokerType)func(std::forward<Arguments>(parameters)...);
    }
private:
    std::intptr_t address;
};

std::string test(const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return "I have returned";
}

int main(void) {
    using test_print_type = std::string (*)(const std::string& str);
    Invoker<test_print_type> get_value{ (std::intptr_t)test };

    auto ret = get_value.invoke("Hello I am a testing function\n");

    std::cout << ret << std::endl; // Errors here
    std::system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're creating an `Invoker` object with template parameters, but the `Invoker` class is not templated?

Comment: Sorry, edited the post. Forgot to include it in the code format.

Comment: Why are you casting the result of your function call?

Comment: using C style casts can mask otherwise very useful compiler errors. I'd also suggest using [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to actually make the call as it can call all actual invokable types

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Edna Mode says, "No casts!"

Comment: @Ambition I can't even get this to [compile on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Gcshx454M) GCC (reasonably) fails

Comment: do you want `invoke` to return `std::string (*)(const std::string& str)` or `std::string`? Right now it's the former, but I think you want the latter.

Comment: Yeah basically I want to wrap a function address in memory and instead of manually defining the function, then call. I want Invoker to call the function using the address variable which points to the address of a function in memory. Then get the return result and then return that result from invoke. I'm sorry, I'm pretty bad at explaining. I tried xd

Comment: @Ambition have a [C++20 type safe version](https://godbolt.org/z/ssEonaMGx)

Comment: @Mget1z This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the value from the invoked function, I think you need to separate the return type into its own template parameter.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class ReturnType, class...Args>
class Invoker {
public:
    Invoker(std::intptr_t address) :
        address(address)
    {  }

    ReturnType invoke(Args&&... parameters) {
        auto func = (ReturnType(*)(Args...)) address;
        return func(std::forward<Args>(parameters)...);
    }
private:
    std::intptr_t address;
};

std::string test(const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return "I have returned";
}

int main(void) {
    Invoker<std::string, const std::string&> get_value{ (std::intptr_t)test };

    auto ret = get_value.invoke("Hello I am a testing function\n");

    std::cout << ret << std::endl; // Errors here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. I was trying to avoid defining the return value explicitly. But this is good too. Thank you